# python regular expression with * not matching

Tags: python, regex

I am learning python. I am using python 3.6

```
reObject = re.compile(r'(ab*)')
mo1 = reObject.search('My name is abbb')
print (mo1.group())
```

The above code matches only `a` in 'name' instead of `abbb`

However the below code matches properly.

```
reObject = re.compile(r'(ab*)')
mo1 = reObject.search('My nme is abbb')
print (mo1.group())
```

How to match a string if the alphabet appears before in the searched string?

Comment: You want it to match `a` followed by 1 or more `b`s?

Comment: You could use the pattern `r'(ab*).*(ab*)'`

Comment: It's really unclear what you want. Do you actually want to match a different expression? Or do you want to find all the matches? Or do you only want to find the last match? Often, the real answer is "the regex doesn't do what I hope it would" for which the first step towards a solution is to properly explain what you hope.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html is a good resource for regex

the * character means find 0 or more
this will find a with 0 b's

the + character means find 1 or more

so (ab+) will find abbb

Answer (score 0):

See [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

> *
>   Causes the resulting RE to match **0 or more** repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. **ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s**.
>
> +
>   Causes the resulting RE to match **1 or more repetitions** of the preceding RE. a**b+ will match ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s**; it will not match just ‘a’.

If you are concerned about why `ab*` is only matching the first `a`, it technically doesn't. The issue is with how you are using the pattern:
 [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) only scans for the first match. If you want to find all matches, look at [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).